# Joining budget figures to first match (join)

Tags: sql, join, pivot

I have a sub table (TABLE 2) which contains multiple locations and car categories, with a budget column.

[image]

I want to left join Table 2 to my main table, which contains customer names, with multiple locations and car categories, plus 20 extra columns.

From my main table, how do I join my Table 2, to the first match and not to every column. For example:

[[image]
(and not have the grey ones appear).

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  It is not clear how you define "first", so this just puts the value on an arbitrary row:

```
select m.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by member, borough, car order by member) = 1
             then t2.target
        end)
from main m left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.borough = m.borough and t2.car = m.car;
```

If you don't want a `case` expression for every column, you can use a subquery like this:

```
select m.*, t2.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by member, borough, car order by member) as seqnum
      from main m
     ) m left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.borough = m.borough and
        t2.car = m.car and
        m.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since table T2 appears to contain unique rows the duplication (caused by LEFT JOIN) must come from replicated values in the main table.  To ensure the join is performed on unique combinations from the main table you could SELECT DISTINCT values in a common table expression.  Something like this

```
with unq_main_cte as (
    select distinct [Name], borough, car
    from main)
select m.*, isnull(t2.[target], 0) [target]
from unq_main_cte m
     left join table2 t2 on t2.borough = m.borough and t2.car = m.car;
```